# Easy to implement proof of shuffle

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, elgamal-encryption, voting

I will be writing some code to implement a non interactive proof of shuffle. I intend to use it on a voting application that supports Borda voting.
The voter must prove that her vote is valid, that is a permutation of 0..c-1 where c is the number of candidates.The vote is encrypted using lifted El Gamal.
However the bibliography is huge on shuffle proofs and I am kind of lost.
Can you recommend a paper/scheme that is easy to implement, practical and correct of course.

Comment: That's dangerously close to asking for a subjective list of references...

Answer (score 3):

Andrew Neff's verifiable shuffle scheme [A Verifiable Secret Shuffle and its Application to E-Voting](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~rfid/p116-neff.pdf) is implemented by the [DeDiS Advanced Crypto Library for Go](https://github.com/dedis/crypto)

A working example program that uses the code is the server from the [Riffle](https://github.com/kwonalbert/riffle) anonymous communication system.

Here's a "mostly finished" standalone implementation in Go, including a paper explaining the protocol: https://github.com/cjpatton/shuffle.git